# How to implement Razorpay auto capture on a static website?

Tags: razorpay

I'm using Razorpay and it works well but I have to login and capture the payments every 5 days or so. I'm using this script to process donations on my Static website. But it seems like I cannot get the auto capture working.

```
<script>
$('#rzp-button1').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();

    var options = {
    "key": "XXXXXXXXXXX",
    "name": "Some name",
    "description": "Some description",
    "amount": "100000", 
    "handler": function (response){
       alert("Payment successful")
    }
}
};
   var rzp1 = new Razorpay(options);
   rzp1.open()
});    
</script>
```

I have tried `captured: 1;` and `payment_capture: 1;` but they don't seem to do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Razorpay now has an auto-capture option in their dashboard which can be found in **Settings >> Payment capture**

Comment: do you mean that no need to write the code for payment capture?

Comment: Yes, the new option does it automatically if set to **automatic**

Answer (score 1):

The javascript code which you mentioned only captures the payments, you need to send the payment details to the server to get it auto authorize.

Refer to doc's https://github.com/razorpay/razorpay-php